# rails 3: how build a string catenating all values of a single field, without iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

If my table Foo contains a field `:code`

If Foo has 3 records with :code = "AAAA" "BBBB" and "CCCC"

I'm trying to build a string

```
"AAAA_BBBB_CCCC"
```

(I'm passing a set of field values to an external program via URL and that's how it expects multiple values to be passed to it)

Doing

```
Foo.select("code").join("_")
```

doesn't work because the items joined are not the actual value of "code", but some sort of hash or association which has an attribute called "code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe

```
Foo.select("code").map(&:code).join("_")
```

but this isn't properly *without iteration* ...

Comment: you're right... i guess I meant without my code doing the iteration manually! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thkink you could resolve this with **composed_of** method instead of simple concatenation
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods/composed_of